# JBoss Developer Studio Third Party Plugins

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, aptana

I am currently looking at development IDEs and one that I am considering is JBoss Developer Studio.  Since the system is based on Eclipse, I was wondering if it was possible to install third party plugins?

In particular, I am interested in being able to install plugins such as Aptana so that I can get Ruby on Rails support.

Does anyone know if third-party Eclipse plugins can be installed to JBoss Developer Studio and if there are any complications in doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed JBoss Developer Studio and now you want to install more plugins then you can use Help > Install New Software.Its may be what you are looking for.